# Deleting apps from ArgoCD

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

I am trying to delete applications from ArgoCD in my cluster but it does not work. I made the mistake of deleting the namespace of ArgoCD directly, thinking that it will remove all the resources linked to it. I have no more resources apart from the applications related to ArgoCD

I manage to display these applications

[image]

But when it comes to delete them, no ressources found.

[image]

[image]

Comment: not sure if you tried but, since the application.argoproj.io is namespaced, did you try specify the right namespace? Maybe they are inside namespace argocd or something like that.

Comment: I did it but the operation took a long time, I've edited the question to see

Comment: So what is the ultimate result ? Have your resources been deleted successfully once you specified the correct namespace ? What happens if you try to delete an individual resource related with your app ?

Comment: @mario I ended by removing all my cluster and recreating a new one

Comment: Pretty sure when you delete the custom resource descriptor (CRD) for argocd application, kubernetes will delete the application resources as well. Deleting the argocd namespace will delete the CRDs as well.


https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/custom-resources/custom-resource-definitions/#delete-a-customresourcedefinition.


This will however cause a problem as the application finalisers will not be honoured. Meaning that the actual applications resources (eg deployment, service etc) will not be deleted.